# How to extract Text inside round brackets using regular expression extractor in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

onclick=\"hire_request.selectCustomer('85B0B91200000000DCE70982AD546FE44FB2E0DA922F6B50');\">\r\n\r\n

Above is the response for one of the requests and I need to extract value inside hire_request.selectCustomer('"**This Value**"') for passing it to further requests in Jmeter using regular expression extractor.Please help

Comment: What was your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
const str = `onclick=\"hire_request.selectCustomer('85B0B91200000000DCE70982AD546FE44FB2E0DA922F6B50');\">\r\n\r\n`;

const match = str.match(/selectCustomer\('([^\)]+)'\)/);
console.log(match[1]);
```